# Check to see if user exists (all the user accounts are stored in a file)

Tags: c++, io

I am learning file handling in C++. Just for a test I have written this small code. Basically what I want to do is make a user account program using file handling. So I want to use `if else` or `while` in my program to compare the data in the file.

For instance if a user enters his username as "john" the program should be able to search for the name john in the file and if it exists, it should allow the user to sign in and same with the password.

The code I have written is just a file writing test. Please help me out with the actual code. I am a beginner so sorry if it is too silly.

Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
void main () {
  ofstream file;
  file.open("C:\tests1.txt", ios::trunc);

  char name[50];
  cout<<"\nEnter your name: ";
  cin>>name;
  file<<"Username: "<<name;
  file.close();
  cout<<"Thank you! Your name is now in the file";

  ifstream file("tests1.txt");
  if(file=="Username: Chinmay") {
    cout<<"If else successfull\n";
  } else {
    cout<<"If else failed\n";
  }
  _getch();
}
```

Guys please help me out!!

Comment: You should divide your code into registration of new users and login (use some main menu for it).

Comment: You compare the file stream object directly to a string. You need to *read* the contents of the file. I recommend you try to find a C++ stream tutorial, or at least a good [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two solutions and they are quite simple and rough. You may need to improve. Hope this may get you started.

- If you have only small number of users and you need to check user account frequently, you may read in all the username and password, and store them in a `std::map`, where the key is `username` and the value is `password`.

  Suppose that the `username` and `password` are stored in the file as below (separated by space):

  ```
  user1 password1 user2 password2
  ```

  You may implement the above idea like:

  ```
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("input.txt");
  map<string, string> m;
  while(!fin.eof())
  {
      string username, password;
      fin >> username >> password;
      m[username] = password;  // store in a map
  }
  fin.close();
  // check account from user input
  string user, pwd;
  cin >> user >> pwd;
  if (m.find(user) != m.end())
      if (m[user] == pwd)
          // login
      else
          // wrong password
  else
      // reject
  ```
- If the number of users are quite large, you may read in the username and password one by one, and check account immediately.

  ```
  while(!fin.eof())
  {
      string username, password;
      fin >> username >> password;
      if (username == user)
      {
          if (password == pwd)
              // login
          else
              // wrong password
          break;
      }
  }
  // didn't find user and reject
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string name = "";
    string line = "";
    fstream f;
    f.open("a.txt");

    cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    if (f.is_open())
  {

      while (f.good() )
    {


         getline(f,line);
         if(line==name)
         {
            cout<<"You can log in";
                        //Or do whatever you please in here after the username is found in the file

         }
    }
    f.close();
  }
else 
  {
      cout << "Unable to open file"; 
  }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```